# GitHub API rate-limits on originating IP address

Tags: github, ip, ip-address, github-api, rate-limiting

I made a django app: https://avengers-of-github.herokuapp.com/

I have used GitHub API(unauthenticated users), deployed it using heroku and in GitHub API docs, I read:

```
For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows for up to 60 requests per hour.
Unauthenticated requests are associated with the originating IP address, and not the user making requests.
```

So, what exactly is 'originating IP address' here?
Is it my IP, or the IP of the ones, who're using this App?

Answer (score 2):

The term “originating IP address” means the IP address you're using to connect to GitHub.  For example, if you're connecting to the API from 192.0.2.5, then that's the originating IP address.  So in all likelihood, it's the IP of wherever your app is deployed.

Note that this rate limit is shared by all of the people using that IP, so if multiple Heroku apps are using the same outbound IP, then the rate limit will be shared by all of them.

It should go without saying, but since you're not authenticated, it's not possible to associated your requests with a user, and as a result, the rate limits are for your IP and not any user.

Comment: " it's the IP of wherever your app is deployed.": yes, provided it matches the one declared in the application definition, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The OP isn't using a GitHub App; they're using unauthenticated requests.  In addition, GitHub rate limits by IP based on the incoming IP their servers see.

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated in [this example](https://github.com/jupyterhub/the-littlest-jupyterhub/blob/master/docs/howto/auth/github.rst), the "originating IP address" is the one you have declared when [declaring/configuring the GitHub application](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/creating-a-github-app/):

> If you are using a virtual machine from a cloud provider and stop the VM, then when you re-start the VM, the provider will likely assign a new public IP address to it. In this case, you must update your GitHub application information with the new IP address.

In your case, the IP of the URL you have declared in your GitHub application.

[image: Creating a GitHub App]

> In "User authorization callback URL", type the full URL to redirect to after a user authorizes an installation.
>   This URL is used if your app needs to identify and authorize user-to-server requests.

So *not*  the "IP of the ones  who are using this App"